# Edit @everyone role permissions on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a lock command for my discor bot using discord.py, and using an `all` parameter I wanted to lock all channels where @everyone had the permissions to send messages.

This is what I came up with:

```py
permissions = discord.Permissions()
permissions.update(
    view_channel = True,
    read_message_history = True,
    send_messages = False,
    connect = False,
    add_reactions = False,
    use_application_commands = False,
    create_public_threads = False,
    send_messages_in_threads = False
)

role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="@everyone")

await role.edit(permissions = permissions)
```

The only problem is that doing that nothing is changed in the role permissions, and nothing is shown in the audit log.

I really don't know where to hit my head with this, any help is really appreciated

Comment: You mentioned "nothing is changed in the role permissions" -- show us the details of how you made that observation. It would help us to help you. You appear to be following some reference material about `permissions.update( ... )` -- share the URL of such documentation as part of your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @J_H I can see nothing is changed from the role settings of the server. 
The permissions.update method is documented here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=permissions#discord.Permissions.update 
I hope I'm not missing something